# Add categories to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using this plugin called Rotating Testimonials by wpbeginner and I have customised to suit my needs, however I need to add the option to add each testimonial to a category and then show the categories on a page and when you click on the category it will take you to a page listing testimonials from that category.

This is the code so far - http://pastebin.com/4mKRqcpu

I am new to this and would like some guidance!

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post _links_ to your code - add it to the question. And always link to all resources that are needed to reproduce your problem or inspect code... for example the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

add this code below in your plugin after register post type

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'casestudy' );
```

for more read on WordPress codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type)

Comment: hey ok i have added that code and removed the line

'taxonomies' => array('category') - how would i go about showing the case studies in a page according to their category?

Comment: use `get_posts();` or `new WP_Query();`